# How to get my database to reflect changes made to models.py?

Tags: django, django-models

I made a change to my models, and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get my database to reflect my models.  So far I have tried the following:

```
python manage.py shelldb
SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';
DROP TABLE appname_modelname;
```

When I tried that I got: "unknown command: shelldb".

I also tried:

python manage.py dbshell
DROP TABLE accounts_userreview;

No error, but my db still doesn't reflect my models.

Finally, I just altogether deleted my database by dragging it into the trash and then doing syncdb, it then made me create a new superuser, but STILL the database that was created does not reflect the changes to my models.

I'm at a loss here,  What else can I do here?  Also, I'm new to learning Django, is there some kind of layer in between the models and my database?  I would assume there is since deleting and then rebuilding the database didn't work.

Would appreciate any advice here.

Comment: If you get your answer mark it as varified.

Comment: `python manage.py migrate` is what you need.

Comment: If deleting the database and re-running syncdb doesn't work, then you have either not saved the models file, or not updated the one you think you have. Django doesn't add any kind of layer, what would be the point of that?

Answer (score 2):

if you are on Django < 1.7 , you have to use some migration tool i.e. - [South](https://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) . Django 1.7 has inbuilt migration.

For more info [migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/)

Comment: I am running 1.6, and my understanding with South is that I would have needed to be using it BEFORE I made the changes to my model in order to be useful in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Run these commands in terminal to make migrations for Django 1.7
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py syncdb

for Django < 1.7
use South